# SQLite syntax error: while compiling: UPDATE contacts SET name=? WHERE phone=+34

Tags: android, sqlite, contacts

In my project, there's a piece of code that is waiting to be called by `ContentObserver` when there's a change on the contact table. When it happens, I check every contact in the table one by one if had been changed or if one has been created. Then, depending on this, I save my changes on my own table. But it gives me errors. Here's my code:

```
while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            try {
                name = phones
                        .getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                phoneNumber = phones
                        .getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                JSONObject jobject = db.select_contact(name, phoneNumber);

                String type1 = jobject.getString("type");

                if (type1.equals("upload")) {
                    Log.i("********", "Upload on the db" + name + "  "
                            + phoneNumber);
                    db.contact_table(name, phoneNumber);
                } else if (type1.equals("change_name")) {
                    db.update_name(name, phoneNumber);
                    Log.i("********", "Change name and upload " + name);
                } else if (type1.equals("change_phone")) {
                    db.update_name(name, phoneNumber);
                    Log.i("********", "Change phone and upload "
                            + phoneNumber);
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And there's the part where i upload it to my own table created by me:

```
public long update_name(String name, String number) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(NAME, name);
    return ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE_4, cv, NUMBER + "=" + number,
            null);
}

public long update_number(String name, String number) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(NUMBER, number);
    return ourDatabase
            .update(DATABASE_TABLE_4, cv, NAME + "=" + name, null);
}
```

The problem is that on the part of upload changes on the DB, it gives me this errors:

```
07-07 09:28:41.412: W/System.err(11667): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "629": syntax error: , while compiling: UPDATE contacts SET name=? WHERE phone=+34 629 21 00 80
07-07 09:28:41.412: W/System.err(11667):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
07-07 09:28:41.412: W/System.err(11667):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
07-07 09:28:41.412: W/System.err(11667):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
07-07 09:28:41.412: W/System.err(11667):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
07-07 09:28:41.412: W/System.err(11667):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acquireAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:260)
07-07 09:28:41.412: W/System.err(11667):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:84)
07-07 09:28:41.412: W/System.err(11667):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1936)
07-07 09:28:41.412: W/System.err(11667):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1887)
07-07 09:28:41.412: W/System.err(11667):    at com.background.Database.update_name(Database.java:215)
07-07 09:28:41.417: W/System.err(11667):    at com.extract.Contacts.onChange(Contacts.java:69)
07-07 09:28:41.417: W/System.err(11667):    at android.database.ContentObserver$NotificationRunnable.run(ContentObserver.java:43)
07-07 09:28:41.417: W/System.err(11667):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-07 09:28:41.417: W/System.err(11667):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-07 09:28:41.417: W/System.err(11667):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-07 09:28:41.417: W/System.err(11667):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
07-07 09:28:41.422: W/System.err(11667):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 09:28:41.422: W/System.err(11667):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-07 09:28:41.422: W/System.err(11667):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
07-07 09:28:41.422: W/System.err(11667):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
07-07 09:28:41.422: W/System.err(11667):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
WHERE phone=+34 629 21 00 80
```

Should be this:

```
WHERE phone="+34 629 21 00 80"
```

Comment: Wrong kind of quotes. But better: use a 2nd query parameter; it avoids the quoting *and* possible SQL injection.

Comment: Or a like query. WHERE phone LIKE "+36%".

Comment: It will be better like this : phone='+34 633 34 22 34' ?

Comment: Those quotes `""` still works in MySQL I've been working recently. But in PostgreSQL only `''` are correct.

Comment: Well, that would be correct .. until user enters `'--DROP TABLE IMPORTANTSTUFF;` as a phone number. Hey, it can happen.

Comment: @KamilKokot SQLite doesn't support broken `"string"` syntax.

Comment: How can `'--DROP TABLE IMPORTANTSTUFF;` works? Can you explain me? `--` means comment, so `DROP TABLE IMPORTANTSTUFF;` wouldn't be processed.

Comment: No it's the same error. The problem it's not on the quotes... @pst

Comment: @KamilKokot It won't. That's the point. It's an SQL injection. Imagine that was supplied as **data** to a string-concatenation SQL.

Comment: it can be the name of the contacts? ALSKDFS ASDFAS ? because of the space?

Comment: @pst `UPDATE contacts SET name=? WHERE phone='+34  '--DROP TABLE IMPORTANTSTUFF;` I imagined and?

Comment: @KamilKokot Did you **take the time** to see how the query was constructed? The number is not a literal embedded in it. It comes from an outside source. (Of course my proposed injection was slightly incorrect as the `--` would comment it out.)

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. To test the String value in SQL, you should use "Like" operator.

Your Where statement should be this :

```
WHERE phone LIKE "+34 629 21 00 80"
```

This is the correct answers :

```
public long update_name(String name, String number) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(NAME, name);
    return ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE_4, cv, NUMBER + " LIKE ?",
        new String[]{number});
}

public long update_number(String name, String number) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(NUMBER, number);
    return ourDatabase
        .update(DATABASE_TABLE_4, cv, NAME + " LIKE ?", new String[]{name});
}
```

Comment: The problem it's not that, the problem it's basicly that the name variable has not been catch : SET name = ? WHERE phone ="+34 67853435"

Comment: The escappe "?" is not catch in the error log and it's normal. Android catch this automaticly in the SGBD but we can't see this in the logcat